# Is there a way to include build number in webpack bundle output(css/js file)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, webpack-2

Right now I have an issue where deployed .js and .css files are cached by our clients browsers. Which means they have to do a hard refresh(CTRL+F5) in order to get the newest updated .js file from the server. This obviously isn't good.

I have seen it's common practice to force a versioning on the .js and .css files name extension, for example so that `bundle.js` would be named something along the lines of `bundle.js?v={versionnumber}`?

Another challenge would be to dynamically update this reference in an `index.html` file. Is there a way to do this in Webpack as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read this chapter [webpack-caching](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/#the-problem)?

We usually give a `[hash]` as part of bundle name.

And for your second question, you can try [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin)